# effect modification from coxph in R

Tags: r, interaction, cox-regression

I am investigating effect modification in the context of a time-varying cox model in R. My model is as follows:

```
fit1.1<- with (data, coxph(Surv(startdays, enddays, event) ~ age*strata(Region) + BMI.time.var + cluster(id), ties="breslow"))
```

I get the following output:

[image: Interaction Model Output]

What I am really interested in is calculating the effect estimates and 95% CIs for age in each Region from these output for presentation in an effect modification table. To this end, I'd like to be able to estimate:

Effect estimate for age in: Northeast, South, West, Midwest.

I have not been able to identify code which permits this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try confint(fit1.1).

Also, if you need to extract any other information from fit1.1, try taking a look at the structure of your fitted object, with str(fit1.1) or str(summary(fit1.1)).

Comment: Hi Len, I failed to completely describe what I'm looking for. My apologies.  What I am really interested in is calculating the effect estimates and 95% CIs for age in each Region from these output for presentation in an effect modification table. To this end, I'd like to be able to estimate:

Effect estimate for age in: Northeast, South, West, Midwest.

Comment: No problem. It's a little hard to address this without a sample of the data, but I think "age:strate(Region)Northeast"  (as well as "age:strate(Region)South"  and "age:strate(Region)West")  gives an interaction term for age*region relative to "age:strate(Region)Midwest".

If you just want age estimates and 95% CI confidence intervals for each region, why don't you just split your dataframe into one for each region and do the cox analyses after that step?